# Shuffling cards and the horseshoe map

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, markov-chains, chaos-theory

I wonder if there is a connection between the dynamics of repeated cut & shuffle operations on a deck of cards, and topological chaotic maps such as [the horseshoe map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_map)?
I ask this entirely naively. Pointers to where I could explore such a connection would be appreciated—Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for, but one such connection is provided by [symbolic dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_dynamics). If I remember correctly, a nice introduction to this is in Shub's book *[Global stability of dynamical systems](http://books.google.ch/books?id=KFLvAAAAMAAJ)*.

Comment: Thanks, t.b.!  I just requested Shub's book via Interlibrary Loan.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of shuffling as doubling.  So if the card position starts out $n \in [0,25]$, an out-shuffle sends it to $2n$.  If it starts out  $n \in [26,51]$, an out-shuffle sends it to $2n-1 \pmod {52}=2n-53$.  This is similar to the chaotic system that just strips the first bit off a number.

Comment: Nice observation re stripping off a bit!  Thanks, Ross!